# Equation break in align equations in beamer

Tags: beamer, equations, align, line-breaking

Question:

Here I am working on an example in which I have some equations for which I am using align.

The problem is, can I get next equation on next slide without writing new align environment? Second question: my last equation is very long can I split it?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\setstretch{1.0}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{}{\vspace{-0.4em}} % decrease
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\Pause}[1][]{\unless\ifmeasuring@\relax
    \pause[#1]%
    \fi}
\makeatother

\title[pqr lmn] %optional
{Chapter}

\subtitle{Lecture - 0}

\author[X. Y. Z] % (optional, for multiple authors)
{x.~y.~z \\ abc \\ def}
%\date[\today] % (optional)

\begin{document}
    
\frame{\titlepage}
    \begin{frame}
        %\setstretch{1.0}
        \textbf{Find nth order derivative of} $\boldsymbol{\cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x}$
        \begin{align*}
        y&=\cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x\\[8pt]
        &=\dfrac{1}{2}\cos x \left(2\,\cos 3x \cos 2x\right)\\[12pt]
        &=\dfrac{1}{2}\,\cos x \,\left(\cos 5x + \cos x\right)\\[12pt]
        &=\dfrac{1}{4}\,\left[2 \cos 5x \cos x + 2\cos^2 x\right]\\[12pt]
        &=\dfrac{1}{4}\,\left[\cos 6x + \cos 4x + 1 + \cos 2x\right]
        \end{align*}
    \end{frame}
    
\begin{frame}
        %\setstretch{1.0}   
        $$\therefore\;\;y_n=\dfrac{1}{4}\,\left[\left\{\cos 6x\right\}_n + \left\{\cos 4x\right\}_n + \left\{1\right\}_n + \left\{\cos 2x\right\}_n\right]$$
        $$=\dfrac{1}{4}\,\left[6^n\,\left\{\cos 6x+\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right\} + 4^n\,\left\{\cos 4x+\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right\} + 0 + 2^n\,\left\{\cos 2x+\dfrac{n\pi}{2}\right\}\right]$$
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By changing all instances of `\dfrac` to `\tfrac`, getting rid of all `\left` and `\right` directives, it's possible to write the entire expression on one frame. Oh, and I would get rid of the `\,` thinspaces. They're simply not needed to typeset the math material well.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\setstretch{1.0}
% \usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'beamer' class
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % use non standard fonts
\usefonttheme{serif}             % default family is CM

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \textbf{\boldmath Find the $n$th order derivative of $\cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x$}
    \begin{align*}
        y&=\cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x\\[4pt]
        &=\tfrac{1}{2}\cos x (2\cos 3x \cos 2x)\\[4pt]
        &=\tfrac{1}{2}\cos x (\cos 5x + \cos x)\\[4pt]
        &=\tfrac{1}{4}[2 \cos 5x \cos x + 2\cos^2 x]\\[4pt]
        &=\tfrac{1}{4}[\cos 6x + \cos 4x + 1 + \cos 2x]\\[8pt] 
    \therefore\quad
    y_n &=\tfrac{1}{4}\bigl[\{\cos 6x\}_n + \{\cos 4x\}_n + \{1\}_n + \{\cos 2x\}_n\bigr] \\[4pt]
        &=\tfrac{1}{4}\bigl[6^n\bigl\{\cos 6x+\tfrac{n\pi}{2}\bigr\} + 4^n\bigl\{\cos 4x+\tfrac{n\pi}{2}\bigr\} +0 \\
        &\qquad + 2^n\bigl\{\cos 2x+\tfrac{n\pi}{2}\bigr\}\bigr]
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum* to address the OP's follow-up request: Here's how I would split the material across two `frame`s if I had to.

```
\documentclass[12pt,fleqn]{beamer}
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usepackage{setspace}
%\usepackage{amsmath} % is loaded automatically by 'beamer'
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % use non standard fonts
\usefonttheme{serif}             % default family is CM

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{Find the $n$th order derivative of $\cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x$}
    \begin{align*}
      y &=\cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x\\[4pt]
        &=\tfrac{1}{2}\cos x (2\cos 3x \cos 2x)\\[4pt]
        &=\tfrac{1}{2}\cos x (\cos 5x + \cos x)\\[4pt]
        &=\tfrac{1}{4}[2 \cos 5x \cos x + 2\cos^2 x]\\[4pt]
        &=\tfrac{1}{4}[\cos 6x + \cos 4x + 1 + \cos 2x]
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{(finding the $n$th order derivative, cont'd)}
    \begin{align*} 
    \therefore\quad
    y_n &=\tfrac{1}{4}\bigl[\{\cos 6x\}_n + \{\cos 4x\}_n + \{1\}_n + \{\cos 2x\}_n\bigr] \\[4pt]
        &=\tfrac{1}{4}\bigl[6^n\bigl\{\cos 6x+\tfrac{n\pi}{2}\bigr\} + 4^n\bigl\{\cos 4x+\tfrac{n\pi}{2}\bigr\} +0 \\
        &\qquad + 2^n\bigl\{\cos 2x+\tfrac{n\pi}{2}\bigr\}\bigr]
    \end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: If you're not sure about using `\tfrac`, do consider employing inline-fraction notation: replace all instances of `\frac{1}{2}` with `(1/2)`, all instances of `\frac{1}{4}` with `(1/4)`, and all instances of `\frac{n\pi}{2}` with `n\pi/2`.

Comment: Ok and thanks a lot for giving answer which is very useful.

Comment: One question if my simplification is continue and it doesn't end in first slide and i have to use another frame can i continue align in second frame also.

Comment: i am asking about allow display break.

Comment: @SDP - Sure. A word of caution about breaking multi-row equations across `beamer` frames: Unless the page  break (frame break??) occurs at some very natural location, you run a serious risk of confusing your audience to no end. (Your focus never drifts off, does it?) My advice: Do *not* incur this risk. Better to use two `frame`s with their own `align` or `align*` environments. In the answer I wrote, for instance, this could be achieved by replacing `\\[8pt]` with `\end{align*}\end{frame}` and, after starting the next `frame`, inserting `\begin{align*}` immediately before `\therefore`.

Comment: Ok i understand one request would you please give the codes for same example which explain your comments. if possible.

Comment: @SDP - Please see the addendum I just posted.

Comment: Great thanks a lot again.